# "предпочитаю" + "живое исполнение" - which case?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

To my knowledge `Живое исполнение` translates to `live performance`

I have the sentence `I prefer live performances` which I attempted to translate into `Я предпочитаю живому исполнениям`

I translated it like this because it is my understanding that I should use the **Dative** case to express feelings or to say you like something.

```
    Мне нравится Москва
    Как вам нравится фильм?
```

Also `живому`is in **Dative Singular** and `исполнениям`is in **Dative Plural** because that's how it is in English, as far as I am aware anyway.

I am trying to disguise this "Is my translation correct?" question as best as I can with some hope that the answer will help someone other than myself.

Comment: Just curious how a native Russian speaker would translate "I prefer TV to live performances." Maybe, in that case, "live performances" would take dative case.

Comment: In Мне нравится Москва, Москва is in Nomenative, only Я (I) is in Dative (so, the form is мне).

Comment: How did u cocnclude that "live" is a singular adjective in English? It has the same form for singular and plural so from what have u conluded it is singular?

Answer (score 8):

Your translation is wrong in several ways. The verb `предпочитать` is transitive, so it can have a direct object, and the direct objects are always in the **Accusative case**.

Also, `исполнение` in this sentence must be in the **Singular**, irrespective of what number is used in English. Although this noun does have a plural form, while talking about music the Singular form is used. And naturally, adjectives must agree with the noun they modify in number, you сannot have a singular adjective modifying a plural noun.

So the correct way to put it is:

> Я предпочитаю живое исполнение.

Comment: Ah, this is how I had it originally before I started messing around and doubting myself. I apologise to anyone who saw my poor Russian.

Answer (score 4):

I'll revisit later the question of whether *живое исполнение* is the correct translation of *live performance* and whether in Russian you can use it in plural.

Using that translation, in the Russian translation of *I prefer live performances*, dative case is not correct and the accusative case needs to be used instead.  In addition, you have a mismatch of singular/plural of adjective and noun (i.e. singular adjective with plural noun).

Overall, the sentence would be translated as

> Я предпочитаю [кого/что] живые исполнения.

This however sounds rather unnatural to a native Russian speaker.  While I have heard *живое исполнение* in the past, it usually was used as a word-for-word translation - and never in plural.

Personally, I would translate the phrase as *концертное исполнение* or *концертное выступление* (which can often be used in plural).

> Тебе нравится последний диск этой группы?
>   Я предпочитаю концертные выступления.
>       или
>   Я предпочитаю концертное исполнение.

Comment: Особенности национального шоу-биза: концертное выступление может быть не "живым" а под фонограмму. Ищите на афишах надпись "живой звук".

Comment: @Artemix К сожалению, это так...

Comment: "Живое исполнение" sounds weird to my Russian ear, unless it's a recent development.

Comment: @VitalyOsipov Totally agree with you - as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The part about cases is already answered, I just want to add that actually most probably you don't need to try to translate as `живое исполнение` at all. It's a valid Russian but in colloquial speech you'd rather hear `вживую`, so, the phrase will be:

> Мне больше нравится, когда играют вживую.

or

> Я предпочитаю, когда вживую исполняют.